# Disable vim text wrapping by file type

Tags: vim

I have a section of my vimrc (which I don't fully understand) that wraps text over 80 columns and and if there is such a line, colors the excess red.

```
set textwidth=80
set tw=80
set wrap
highlight OverLength ctermbg=red ctermfg=white guibg=#592929
match OverLength /\%81v.\+/
```

This works quite well in general but I want to disable the entire thing (wrapping and matching) when the filetype is `.py` (and in principle, other filetypes).

Similar, but not quite the same question at [Limiting a match in vim to certain filetypes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1702615/limiting-a-match-in-vim-to-certain-filetypes)

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146410/enablind-and-disabling-word-wrap-automatically-on-different-file-extensions-on-v

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, a note: `tw` and `textwidth` are the same thing (`tw` is just the abbreviated name, variables generally have a long and short form) so you only need one of those first two lines in any case.

I suspect what you're really looking for is what I was looking for earlier, which is: how to keep settings specific to various file types.  It actually gets fairly complicated because some settings (like `textwidth`) are what vim calls "local to buffer", and others (like `wrap`) are "local to window".  The difference boils down to what happens if you (for example) run `vim foo.txt` and then use `:split` to get two windows viewing `foo.txt`.  There is now one buffer, hence one `textwidth`, for `foo.txt`, but there are two windows, hence two `wrap`s.

Until you start using this feature for things, though, you probably just want to try out the suggestions in http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip1510 for making each setting depend on what `filetype` is set to.  Editing a file named `foo.py` will use the Python settings, because vim automatically sets `filetype=python` for files whose name ends in `.py`.  You can manually set the file type (`:set filetype=whatever`) if the file name suffix is unknown or ambiguous (e.g., when editing file `zog` which has no suffix at all but is actually a shell script, you can manually `:set filetype=sh`), and there is a lot of other info you can find on making vim automatically recognize particular file types.

(Another side note: I don't agree with their setting `tabstop=4`; I use `softtabstop=4` and `smarttabs` and `expandtabs` so that I get nothing but spaces in my *.py files.  This avoids the fight over whether tabs are placed at every 4 or 8 columns. :-) )

As for highlighting long lines in general, see http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Highlight_long_lines for an explanation of what you're doing now, and why it's obsoleted if you have vim 7.3.  See also [vim-80-column-layout-concerns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235439/vim-80-column-layout-concerns).