# How can I cancel out a match pattern for a particular file extension?

Tags: vim

I currently have the following line in my vimrc to highlight lines longer than 80 characters wide.

```
match ErrorMsg '\%>80v.\+
```

I would like this rule to be disabled when I am editing a SQL file, so I tried adding this line based on what I read in the help.

```
 autocmd BufNew,BufRead *.sql :match ErrorMsg none
```

However, this throws the following error whenever I load a sql file.

```
Error detected while processing BufRead Auto commands for "*.sql":
E488: Trailing characters: :match ErrorMsg none
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

How can I make it work without throwing the error?

Comment: I ran into a similar issue and this worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1702770/42388

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the highlight group. (colon removed since it doesn't affect the outcome)

```
autocmd BufNew,BufRead *.sql match none
```

You are only allowed 3 matches and you need to use either match, 2match or 3match. So you only need to clear the specific one that you used

Notice how in `:h :match` `{group}` is not listed in the syntax for match none

```
:mat[ch]
:mat[ch] none
                Clear a previously defined match pattern.
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: In recent Vim 7.3+ versions, you can alternatively use:

```
:setlocal colorcolumn=81
```

in your otherwise identical `:autocmd`.

Also note that both this and your `:match` are window-local, so if you switch buffers, the highlighting will persist. To completely fix this (mere nuisance) would require more elaborate autocmds.